# Updating issues using Jira Rest Java Client (JRJC) in groovy/java

Tags: java, rest, groovy, jira

I need to manipulate fields issues based on either `fixVersion` or `label` and set new values there. I found that JRJC 3.0.0 is at least useful to get issues based on it's keys, read out the labels and other fields and so on.

It looks like this:

```
def jirakey = 'FOOBAR-123'
def issue = this.restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(jiraKey).claim()
```

While you can do stuff like voting for the issue, set new transitions or even create new issues, I did not find any method to update the fields, say `fixVersion` or `labels`.

There's an issue at the atlassian folks jira, saying, that [this issue has been solved](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JRJC-64) but I can't follow it, because there's no functionality updating issues and within the comments there's even code fragments showing how to circumvent the missing feature.

Additionally I found a more recent question "[Is there up-to-date documentation on using JRJC in a JIRA plugin?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31680652/is-there-up-to-date-documentation-on-using-jrjc-in-a-jira-plugin)" where the answer was enlightening: "Throw away jira-rest-java-client-api and do direct calls to JIRA REST API."

Is there any suggestion to use the library nevertheless and how would you implement the missing feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't looked it up thourougly enough. So the answer to my question is to use the method [IssueRestClient.updateIssue()](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client-api/3.0.0/jira-rest-java-client-api/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/api/IssueRestClient.html#updateIssue(java.lang.String,%20com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.IssueInput)) which is available since JRJC-3.0.0.